# Negative SMPTE timecode drop-frame handling?

Tags: sync, timecode

How are negative timecodes handled with drop-frame:

- Is the frame before `-00:00:59:29` labelled `-00:00:01:02` (symmetric), or
- Is the frame after `-00:01:00:01` labelled `-00:00:59:28` (regular)?

Thanks.

Comment: Negative timecodes are not mentioned in SMPTE-12, the relevant standard, so I presume that as with timecodes > 24 hours the behaviour is implementation defined. FFMPEG's timecode flags allow for negative timecodes, you could check their implementation: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/timecode_8h_source.html

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old Q, but it should be pointed out that a 'negative timecode' makes no sense. The SMPTE frame before 00:00:00:00 is 23:59:59:29. The namespace for drop frame (and non-drop) codes is already well-defined -- no need to postulate negative values. If there are systems or programs that use this notation, they should be rethought.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account that

- frame dropping works on a 10min-regular basis
- project offsetting by a multiple of 10min should keep frame dropping at the same positions

I guess the correct way of doing this is on a **regular** basis.